# MatLab and Arduino. Does anyone know how to establish a connection?

Tags: matlab, arduino, signal-processing, matlab-figure

I have this Arduino UNO R3 board with DIP ATmega328P and matlab.fig file. What I want to do is control the traffic lights using the figure file of MatLab. The Traffic light consists of Red and Green LED only and will be operated by a push button. I have scoured the internet and got some very few results. Please help me guys :( Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with the [MATLAB Support Package for Arduino (aka ArduinoIO Package)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32374-matlab-support-package-for-arduino-aka-arduinoio-package) from the file exchange.
And there are several tutorials out there, here is [one](http://allaboutee.com/2011/07/04/how-to-send-data-from-the-arduino-to-matlab/), and [another one](http://creat-tricks.blogspot.com/2013/01/arduino-and-matlab-gui.html).

Comment: Thank you for the links. Didn't see this sites while searching :)

Comment: The [another one](http://creat-tricks.blogspot.com/2013/01/arduino-and-matlab-gui.html) link will help me for sure